# boost::shared_mutex vs boost::mutex for multiple threads writing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

I have a scenario where multiple threads are writing to a common buffer (a map), each thread could or could not have the same key. Can someone please advise on whether i should use boost::shared_mutex or just boost::mutex? My understanding is that boost::shared_mutex is for a single writer and multiple reads which is not what i want. Does this make boost::mutex more appropriate for this scenario?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `boost::shared_mutex` is not your case as you don't have pure readers and have multiple writers. Just use `boost::mutex` to enforce exclusive access to shared data.